# Working with SetTag method to choose a ListView item

Tags: java, android, android-listview

```
        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                R.id.textView1,
                (String[]) myArr.toArray(new String[]{})));
    }

         class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
                             final int which;

                public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                    int textViewResourceId, String[] string) {
                    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, string);
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    int which=position;
                    LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent,false);            
                    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

                    tv.setTag(position);
                    iv.setTag(position);
                    tb.setTag(position);

                    tv.setText(myArr.get(position).toString());

                    tb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(tb.isChecked()){
                                    which=(Integer) tb.getTag();

                        }else{

                        }


                    }
                    });

                    return row;
                }
        }

}
```

Hello I am trying to work with the setTag view method to detect what items is pressed. my layout is composed of a list each row containing a textfield a togglebutton and an imageview. I would like to change the image of the row containing the pressed button. I have gone this far and i'm stuck on how to continue can i get some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply the position passed to your `getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`. Just make it final and access it directly without the need to make tag.

However, you should use tagging of views in order to make use of handling scrollable views offered by android.

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
                             final int which;
ArrayList<Boolean> mListImageStates = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
 public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,
   int textViewResourceId, String[] string) {
   super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, string);
    for(int i = 0; i<string.length;i++)
    {
        mListImageStates.add(new Boolean(false));
    }
 }
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
int which=position;
LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

 ChildViewHolder holder = new ChildViewHolder();
 if(convertView == null){
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent,false);
      holder.mTv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      holder.mIv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      holder.mTb = (ToggleButton) row.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
      convertView.setTag(holder)}
 else
 {
      holder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }
 holder.mTv.setText(myArr.get(position).toString());

  holder.mTb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {        
         boolean listState = mListImageStates.get(position);
         mListImageStates.set(position,new Boolean(!listState));
         notifyDataSetChanged();

}});

if(mListImageStates.get(position) == false)
{
//TODO
}else
{
//TODO
}

   return convertView;
}
class ChildViewHolder
{
    public TextView mTv;
    public ImageView mIv;
    public ToggleButton mTb;
}
```

Comment: how can i then change the content of the imageview based on the position the setimage method only takes the drawable argument and do not take the position

Comment: Then, you have to leave an arraylist of boolean that contain the state of each row of your listview. and in your onClick on this view, change the boolean value then, call notifyDataSetChanged(). and in your adapter make the following if(statusArraylist.get(position)) and based on this value change your imageview

Comment: mmm ok i got lost this is new to me a bit :D i should probably go get a book

Comment: Never mind. I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: oh thanks :D i will work on that

Comment: what does the error shown in public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource,int textViewResourceId, String[] string)
                        {
                         super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, string);
                         for(int i = 0; i<string.length;i++)
                         {
                          mListImageStates.add(new Boolean(false));
                         }
                        }
means it is : The blank final field which may not have been initialized

Comment: Sorry for the silly mistake. Check edits

Comment: oh ok thank you i understood the error it was from the "final". i was working on getting caller name in case a phone call do you happen to have an idea on which classes i should use ?

Comment: I haven't worked on such a problem but check this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html

Comment: thank you :D i have finished my application now but with one thing missing i was unable to make it run as a service in the background so it doesn't close and keeps handling the calling... any idea about services and running background applications ? i have tried using the startservice function but couldn't make it work

Comment: First, you need to specify if you need to use IntentService or Service. then you need to add the service you want into your Manifest file. After that handle your service in the way you want. check this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: the application is able to handle the calls and process them even if it is not launched but any user modifications made are reset on closing in example when the user pushes a toggle button for a contact it should play a custom ring on call if button not pushed it should ring with the default one. in my case when closing the application all togglebuttons are reset and the boolen array is set to 0 for all button as if resetted